# ADS won't stop, used task manager still won't stop

Tags: sql-server, ads, advantage-database-server

I am not an IT person but I have to play one at work sometimes. I was about to run diagnostics on our EHR which I do weekly, I always stop the ADS and restart it before running the diagnostics. When I went to stop it this time I got an error box that said operation complete which I've gotten before but the box to restart it never came back, I tried to close it and it said not responding. After waiting 10-15 minutes I used the task manager to end ADS. Now when I try to restart it it says it can't because there is another instance running. When I look in the task manager under service the ADS says stopping and has said that for at least 30 minutes now. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: You can get support directly from SAP here: http://scn.sap.com/community/ads/content

Comment: You could try "SC.EXE" to query the status or stop the service if the GUI services manager is not helpful. http://www.herongyang.com/Windows/Service-Query-Start-Stop-Services-with-sc-exe.html